# Exit condition 41 on SNOPT

Tags: drake

I'm trying to run an optimization with SNOPT.

Right now as I run it I consistently get exit condition 41.

I've added the following parameters to the solver:

```
prog.SetSolverOption(solver.solver_id(),"Function Precision","1e-6")
prog.SetSolverOption(solver.solver_id(),"Major Optimality Tolerance","1e-3")
prog.SetSolverOption(solver.solver_id(),"Superbasics limit","600")
#print("Trying to Solve")
result = solver.Solve(prog)
print(result.is_success())
```

But I still contently get the same exit condition.

The error seems to be from the interpolation function I'm using. (When I remove it I no longer get the error).

```
t, c, k = interpolate.splrep(sref, kapparef, s=0, k=3)

kappafnc = interpolate.BSpline(t, c, k, extrapolate=False)
```

Here is the function I think I determined was causing the issue:

```
  def car_continous_dynamics(self, state, force, steering):
        beta = steering
        s = state[0]
        #print(s)
        n = state[1]
        alpha = state[2]
        v = state[3]
        #State = s, n, alpha , v
        #s= distance along the track, n = perpendicular distance along the track
        #alpha = velocity angle relative to the track
        #v= magnitude of the velocity of the car

        s_val = 0
        if s.value() >0:
          s_val = s.value()
          
        
        Cm1 = 0.28
        Cm2 = 0.05
        Cr0 = 0.011
        Cr2 = 0.006
        m = 0.043
        phi_dot = v*beta*15.5
        Fxd = (Cm1 - Cm2 * v) * force - Cr2 * v * v - Cr0 *tanh(5 * v)
        s_dot = v*cos(alpha+.5*beta)/(1)##-n*self.kappafunc(s_val))
        n_dot= v*sin(alpha+.5*beta)
        alpha_dot = phi_dot #-s_dot*self.kappafunc(s_val)
        v_dot=Fxd/m*cos(beta*.5)

        # concatenate velocity and acceleration
        #print(s_dot)
        #print(n_dot)
        #print(alpha_dot)
        #print(v_dot)
        state_dot = np.array((s_dot,n_dot,alpha_dot,v_dot))
        #print("State dot")

        #print(state_dot.dtype.name)
        #print(state_dot)
        #print(state_dot)
        return state_dot
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging INFO 41 in SNOPT is generally challenging, it is often caused by some bad gradient (but could also due to the problem being really hard to optimize).

You should check if your gradient is well-behaved. I see you have

```py
s_val = 0
if s.value() >0:
    s_val = s.value()
```

There are two potential problems

1. Your `s` carries the gradient (you could check `s.derivatives()`, it has non-zero gradient), but when you compute `s_val`, this is a `float` object with no gradient. Hence you lose the gradient information.
2. `s_val` is non-differentiable at 0.

I would use `s` instead of `s_val` in your function (without the branch `if s.value() > 0`). And also add a constraint `s>=0` by

```py
prog.AddBoundingBoxConstraint(0, np.inf, s)
```

With this bounding box constraint, SNOPT guarantees that in each iteration, the value of is is always non-negative.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. The reason I tried to use S_val is because otherwise the interpolation functions throws and error.


`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pydrake.autodiffutils.AutoDiffXd'`

In the post above I showed how I made the interpolation function. I'm curious if you have any suggesitons for how to fix that.

Comment: OK, so the problem is that some called functions (possibly interpolate.splrep) only works for float, but not AutoDiffXd object. In that case, you will need a different function (maybe you can write it by yourself) such that the function can work with both float and AutoDiffXd.